# Kubernetes: privileged containers and security concerns

Tags: security, kubernetes

Running a container in privileged mode is discouraged for security reasons.
For example: https://www.cncf.io/blog/2020/10/16/hack-my-mis-configured-kubernetes-privileged-pods/

It seems obvious to me that is is preferable to avoid privileged containers when a non-privileged container instead would be sufficient.

However, let's say I need to run a service that *requires* root access on the host to perform some tasks. Is there an added security risk in running this service in a privileged container (or with some linux capabilities) rather than, for example, a daemon that runs as root (or with those same linux capabilities)? What is the added attack surface?

If a hacker manages to run a command in the context of the container, all right, it is game over. But what kind of vulnerability would allow him to do so that couldn't also be exploited in the case of the aforementioned daemon (apart from sharing the kubeconfig file thoughtlessly)?

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/top-5-most-critical-nginx-vulnerabilities-found/#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20latest%20NGINX,of%20Service%20(DoS)%20attacks.) security article written by the astra security team they have mentioned PHP Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (2020) using which the attacker can get hold of your server. If this process is being run by a non root user the attack surface will be reduced but if the same service is having root user access the attacker can get access to remaining containers. This is the reason why it’s always preferred to have least privileged access configured for all the services, also go through this [document](https://www.practical-devsecops.com/lesson-4-hacking-containers-like-a-boss/) for getting an overview on attacks that can be performed using privileged containers.

Comment: @Odsh hope this has helped you in understanding the threats involved in using the privileged containers. Revert back if you still have something to ask.